# QT convert string to UTF-8

Tags: qt

I'm having some troubles converting a string `Bob RosÃ©n` to `Bob Rosén`

Tried:

```
QString str = v.toObject().value("name").toString(); // Contains Bob RosÃ©n
qDebug() << str.toUtf8(); // Outputs Bob RosÃ©n
```

Any ideas?

Comment: utf8 accents are composed of 2 characters (or more not sure), so when using "toutf8" with `qdebug()` it will show the REAL characters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following works for me. A more elegant solution may exist.

```
QString str = "Bob RosÃ©n";
qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8(str.toLatin1().constData());
```